# Using Makefiles in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, makefile

So I am making a simple operating system in c++ and I have files:

```
loader.s

kernel.cpp

Makefile.mak

linker.ld
```

I know that commands in my makefile are used in Linux but I am using windows so How Am I going to change these codes from Linux terminal to windows cmd:::

Makefile.mak:

```
GPPPARAMS = -m32
ASPARAMS = --32
objects = kernel.o loader.o

%.o: %.cpp
        g++ $(GPPPARAMS) -o $@ -c $<

%.s: %.o
        as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
        ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -O $@ $(objects)

install: mykernel.bin
        sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

I downloaded GNU GCC to my computer so I have LD, g++ ad other stuff

Comment: If you have MinGW installed and use the MinGW shell you don't need to change anything but renaming `Makefile.mak` to `Makefile`. Calling `make install` won't work on windows though. Are you cross compiling?

Comment: All in all it looks your question actually is: _How can I port my own OS to a Windows machine?_

Comment: cmake is automatic, learn how to use it.https://cmake.org/

Comment: I think I am cross compiling But why do I need to change Makefile.mak to Makefile. I dont get it

Comment: _"But why do I need to change Makefile.mak to Makefile"_ Because `Makefile` is the default taken by `make` to lookup (Maybe `Makefile.mak` works as well, not sure).

Comment: _"I think I am cross compiling"_ Doesn't really look like this. You should use a cross-toolchain rather then the standard MinGW GCC then.

Comment: @sailfish009 CMake doesn't really help or add any additional value for the OP's case. I prefer to use GNU Make anyways.

Comment: You can just do make -f Makefile.mak instead of renaming the file.

Comment: where can I download GNU make

Comment: For a very easy setup you could use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), during the installation you can then choose GNU make to be installed with it.